# v0.19.2 hyperledger composer network start failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have already implemented my `.bna` file named "supply-chain-network" but I think that the problem isn't in the `.bna`, since I have tried with another `.bna`(the basic-sample-network in hyperledger composer playground) and the problem still persists.

Composer version: 0.19.2

Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04 running in VM

Steps:

- download the `fabric-dev-servers`
- ./downloadFabric.sh
- ./startFabric.sh
- ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
- exported the basic-sample-network from the playground (my-basic-sample.bna)
- `composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile my-basic-sample.bna@`
- `composer network start --networkName my-basic-sample --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

And I got the following error:

```
Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
```

`Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (my-basic-sample:0.0.1))`

I have checked and the name of the network and the version by issue the command:

```
composer archive list -a my-basic-sample.bna
```

And I got:

`Listing Business Network Archive from my-basic-sample.bna
Identifier:my-basic-sample@0.2.4-deploy.0
Name:my-basic-sample
Version:0.2.4-deploy.0`

`Command succeeded`

I have tried to issue composer network start with version 0.2.4 instead of 0.0.1 and I got the same error.

The log of the docker by typing:

```
docker logs peer0.org1.example.com
```

I got:

[image]

I have seen on https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3591#issuecomment-386718739 that this error is caused by an extra character when copy pasting the command from the hyperledger composer website. I have done what hi2rashid suggests(copy the command to a notepad and then copy to the command line) but I still got the same error.

Anybody know how to fix this ?

Comment: This you manage to fix this problem?
I just ran into it, which is weird because I have been successfully deploying networks for over a month.

Comment: Same problem here..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are very close to getting this working ...

The `composer archive list` command has listed the version as "0.2.4-deploy.0" - although this doesn't look like a version "number" it is.  Your network start command should include  `--networkVersion 0.2.4-deploy.0`

This long version comes from Composer Playground autogenerating versions when the model is upgraded.

Comment: First `composer archive list` is not a full command. Secondly, I can see I have deployed the correct version of network and this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear it doesn't solve your issue @KCloud - but why not add a new question and I'm sure somebody will address it.