# How to fix HyperLedger Composer network start error that reports failure to start container?

Tags: docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am having difficulty starting a new business network using HyperLedger Composer.  I have been following this developer’s guide:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.

I have successfully completed all of the steps leading up to the composer network start command, including installing the network.  When I run:

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

I receive the following error:

> “ ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>
> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers.
>
> Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to
>   execute transaction
>   eda196cff575945b24d2e123823f1b4ba3fefdf8c1525794f7869b47acad906e:
>   error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate
>   platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127
>   "/bin/sh: npm: not found
>
> Command failed “

A few notes:
- I have used "composer archive list -a tutorial-network.bna” to confirm the version and network name
- I have checked that the network name is correct in the start command
- A few of the posts I have read and followed regarding this issue are listed below, and they have not solved the problem I am facing:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4043
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3794
[v0.19.2 hyperledger composer network start failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232772/v0-19-2-hyperledger-composer-network-start-failed)

One thing I have noticed is that the peer admin card is not associated with a business network, as determined by running:

```
composer network list --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1
```

I am not sure how to associate the card with a network, or if that is causing any issues.

Any suggestions regarding what may be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated, thank you.